# ng-table pagenation not update after delete or add new record in the data item

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using np table in **angular for data binding**. ng table show paging and total number of record  but when I add new row or remove one row from data model in ng table.

Total row is reflected but total number of record and paging not reflected.

I have used bleow code 
Any one can help me..

```
$scope.viewDeleteTemplateModel = function (templateId, name) {
    if (parseInt(templateId, 10) <= 0) {
        $scope.bindPopUpMessages(Enum.AlertType.Error, "TemplateId must be greater than zero.");//showing smart popup alert
    } else {
        $scope.bindSmartAlert("<i class='fa fa-fw fa-reorder'></i> Template", "Do you really want to delete the <strong>" + name + "</strong> template?", function () {
        if ($scope.PropertyBag.SmartAlertResult && $scope.PropertyBag.SmartAlertResult === 1) {                    
        var request = "request={'OrganizationId':" + $scope.PropertyBag.OrganizationDetails.OrganizationId + ",'TemplateId':" + templateId + "}";
        $RestService.deleteTemplate(request).success(function (result) {
             if (result) {
                 var alertType = Enum.AlertType.Success;
                 var message = "The Template  <strong>" + name + "</strong> is deleted successfully.";
                 if (result.Result.Status !== 0) {
                     alertType = Enum.AlertType.Error;
                     message = "Opps! Something went wrong that's why the template  <strong>" + name + "</strong> is not deleted.";
                 } else {
                     $scope.tableServerSide[tableId].data.Model.Items = _.without($scope.tableServerSide[tableId].data.Model.Items, _.findWhere($scope.tableServerSide[tableId].data.Model.Items, { TemplateId: templateId }));
                      if ($scope.tableServerSide[tableId].Records !== undefined && $scope.tableServerSide[tableId].Records > 0)
                         {
                             $scope.tableServerSide[tableId].Records = $scope.tableServerSide[tableId].Records - 1;
                         }

                 //$scope.getTemplatesList();
                 }
                  $scope.bindPopUpMessages(alertType, message);//showing smart popup alert                            
              }
           }).error(function (err) { } );
         }
      });
    }
};
```

And My html code...

```
<table id="tblTemplate" ng-init="changeTableDropDownPosition();" ng-table="tableServerSide['TemplateList']" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div><i class="padding-right-5 fa fa-fw fa-reorder txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>Name </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">

                                        <div> <i class="padding-right-5 fa fa-fw fa-calendar txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Create On</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div><i class="padding-right-5 fa fa-fw fa-envelope txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>Message </div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div> <i class="padding-right-5 fa fa-fw fa-file txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>File Name</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-center">
                                        <div> <i class="padding-right-5 fa fa-fw fa-file-o txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>File Type</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="width-9">
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="listItem in $data.Model.Items">
                                    <td>{{listItem.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{listItem.CreateUtc | customdateMili | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{listItem.Message | takechar :'25'}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span ng-if="!configuration.UseAwsMedia">
                                            <a class="no-padding btn btn-link fancybox" ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Image"
                                               href="{{DomainPath}}{{listItem.MediaUrl | removestartchars:2}}"
                                               title="{{listItem.Name}}">{{listItem.FileName | takechar:'20'}}</a>
                                            <span ng-if="listItem.MediaType !== Enum.MediaType.Image"> {{listItem.FileName}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span ng-if="configuration.UseAwsMedia">
                                            <a class="no-padding btn btn-link fancybox" ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Image"
                                               href="{{listItem.MediaUrl}}"
                                               title="{{listItem.Name}}">{{listItem.FileName | takechar:'20'}}</a>
                                            <span ng-if="listItem.MediaType !== Enum.MediaType.Image"> {{listItem.FileName}}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <span ng-if="listItem.MediaUrl">
                                            <i ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Audio" class="fa fa-file-audio-o"></i>
                                            <i ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Video" class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i>
                                            <i ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Image" class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>
                                            <i ng-if="listItem.MediaType === Enum.MediaType.Document" class="fa fa-file"></i>
                                            {{GetEnumName(Enum.MediaType,listItem.MediaType,true)}}
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="viewEditTemplateModel(listItem.TemplateId,listItem.Name)" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Edit">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="viewDeleteTemplateModel(listItem.TemplateId,listItem.Name)" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Delete">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="odd" ng-if="tableServerSide['TemplateList'].Records !==undefined && tableServerSide['TemplateList'].Records === 0">
                                    <td valign="top" colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty"><strong>No Templates</strong> You don't have any Templates yet.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Show us html code with use ng-table

Comment: I have added my html code please once see